# Как вызвать метод из другого контроллера?

Tags: yii

Например, в `SiteController` есть следующая функция

```
public function SCfunc()
{...}
```

Находимся мы на странице, которая под управлением `PageController`, как нам вызвать `SCfunc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать его статическим и `SiteController::SCfunc()`, если он не обращается к `$this`. Либо `Dcfunc` добавить в Controller.php в components, от которого Вы вероятно наследуете все контроллеры и вызывать через `$this->SCfunc();`

Вообще, я так понимаю это не action, поэтому его место в модели.

Comment: про модель учту=)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ оказался простым

```
list($controller) = Yii::app()->createController('site');
$url=$controller->SCfunc();
```

Comment: А если контроллер находится в модуле(например user его контроллер account и нужно вызвать экшн LoginAction), как от туда вызвать? ПРобовал так как вы писали но у меня дал фатальную ощибку
Fatal error: Call to a member function Login() on a non-object